# How to change background color while clicking link or button?

Tags: css, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I am new for oracle mobile application framework. How can i change the different background colors while clicking any link or button. For example I have 3 buttons blue, green and red. If i click blue i want blue background for whole body, If i click red, i want red background for whole body. Like this how can I do this in AMX file.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<amx:view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:amx="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx"
          xmlns:dvtm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx/dvt">
  <amx:panelPage id="pp1">
    <amx:facet name="header">
      <amx:outputText value="Header" id="ot1"/>
    </amx:facet>
    <amx:panelStretchLayout>
      <amx:facet name="top">
        <amx:selectOneButton  id="sob1">
          <amx:selectItem label="One" id="si1"/>
          <amx:selectItem label="Two" id="si2" value="adfmf-panelPage-alternateColor"/>
          <amx:selectItem label="Three" id="si3" value="adfmf-panelPage-springboard"/>
        </amx:selectOneButton>
      </amx:facet>
      <amx:facet name="center">
      <amx:commandButton text="click" id="cb1">
          <amx:showPopupBehavior id="spb1" type="action" align="overlapBottomCenter" decoration="simple" alignId="pp1"
                                 popupId="p1"/>
        </amx:commandButton>
      </amx:facet>
      <amx:facet name="bottom"/>
    </amx:panelStretchLayout>    
  </amx:panelPage>
  <amx:popup id="p1" animation="slideUp" autoDismiss="true" backgroundDimming="off"
             inlineStyle="background-color:#b5e7ff; height:50%; width:60%;">
    <amx:outputText value="Popup is open" id="ot2"/>
  </amx:popup>
</amx:view>
```

Here, there selected Items are there. In this three how can i do the various background.

And How can I refer css file in AMX. Means, In Normal HTML, head section we are giving  like this. In AMX Page how can in refer css file.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me the answer for this question...

Comment: Please check this link, https://community.oracle.com/thread/2414175

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve your target

### Step1

add one `setPropertyListener` in your firstbutton

```
 <amx:setPropertyListener id="spl1" from="blue"
                                             to="#{pageFlowScope.changeColor}" type="action"/>
```

add this to your button according to the colors(in your case blue, green and red)

### Step2

set an `inline` property for the `amx:panelPage` with condition

```
#{pageFlowScope.changeColor eq 'blue' ? 'background-color:blue' : (pageFlowScope.changeColor eq 'red' ? 'background-color:red' : (pageFlowScope.changeColor eq 'green' ? 'background-color:green' : ''))}
```

Comment: Then no need of css?

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve this. If you want to use css then use the above condition with the property styleClass. Then instead of "background-color:blue" you have to write the styleClass corresponds to "background-color:blue"